# How to prevent modify and view user profile in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, profile, drupal-hooks

I would like to prevent specific user (or user group) to modify its profile in Drupal 7.
That means that I would like to hook some function on the event when the user is about to display and change his profile.

The best solution would be if he even could not see his profile, but I don't mean to secure by obscurity (hide the link), because drupalpage.com/user/X would always work.

How can I do that?

PS: perhaps there is any module to be able to achieve the goal without coding?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested but in theory it should work:

```
function yourmodule_exit() {
  $uid = arg(1);
  if(arg(0) == "user" && is_numeric($uid)) {
    drupal_goto("<front>");
  }
}
```